# Retrieve the Request Headers from a page

Tags: python

Is there a possible way to retrieve the content of request header from a page such as this:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:SPC_IA=-1; SPC_EC=-; SPC_F=oTIBQWRUjdH7sWSqJu1UBBA1o3zy5j1C; REC_T_ID=9af9f032-8d77-11e7-b124-1866da5681e2; SPC_T_ID="VkC0m8L3ZwixZk8y836Lhq4XucdTWJQtxOT+CCjn+u7HhYZ0zEcK/BI8L3dT2/em76AgwKj3p9ysfh7yUnOrq9CqS4lRPFaqLTpEuecgX8U="; SPC_U=-; SPC_T_IV="PA3yjLFENXXf8Tzq685zSg=="; csrftoken=SiNmh7GZo00aZ3a0gxIqEaNjB38zhCQI; bannerShown=true; django_language=id; sessionid=15fgkr8ohrult2zkmgu2xyiwwnm4ejcx; SPC_SC_TK=; UYOMAPJWEMDGJ=; SPC_SC_UD=; SPC_SI=i94582s7ffe99b47y3qomp1siqy4adz5
Host:shopee.co.id
If-None-Match:"75c23fc0e3e55d18c21158ab8a335ab4;gzip"
If-None-Match-:55b03-c56af1c195a559f1680c15f63d56f07a
Referer:https://shopee.co.id/SHARP-LED-TV-24INCH-LC24LE175ITT_sby-Area-Surabaya-i.24413460.298360054
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
X-API-SOURCE:pc
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

I want to store the value of "If-None-Match-: xxxx" in my code without having to manually do it, so for every page I open using the for loop that I have in my code, every page's "If-None-Match-: xxxx" value is saved as a variable.

I tried using

```
r = requests.get(url)
r.headers
```

But it only prints out the HTTP response header.

I was wondering if there's a way.

Comment: You are in the client side, not in the server side.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE So I'm assuming it isn't possible? Thank you.

Comment: its possible r.request.headers

Answer (score 2):

For getting the header of client side request header you need to get `re.request.headers`

```
import requests
res = requests.request('GET', "https://www.google.com")
print res.request.headers
```

Output

```
{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.13.0'}
```

Comment: You should accept the ans if it gives correct required answer.

Comment: But it does not return the key and value of "If-None-Match-", that's the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: if you are doing it in python requests module it won't add extra headers unless manually done. you should use selenium for the automated custom headers or mechanize browser. It will be only printed in the headers if it is present. so for a default request in python it won't be present.